# Como habilitar o debug() no PHP?

Tags: debug, xdebug

Estou tendo problemas ao tentar usar a função `debug();` no `PHP`.

---

No log do `apache` aparece o seguinte erro:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function debug() in /var/www/html/...autoload.php:7

Ou seja, na linha 7 do arquivo `autoload.php` eu coloquei o seguinte teste para testar se está funcionando a função `debug()`:

```
<?php
    //session_start();
    //phpinfo();
    $f = "oi";
    echo $f;
    var_dump($f);
    debug($f);
    die();
?>
```

Mas sem sucesso, alguém já passou por isso, ou sabe como solucionar esse erro ?

---

*Obs.: Estou usando o `xdebug-2.6.0beta1`*

Comment: Tem o link da documentação essa função?

Comment: Do `Xdebug` tem esse https://xdebug.org/docs/

Comment: Mas eu já usei em outros projetos apenas a função `debug($variavel);` e funcionava, bastava apenas ativar o debug no `php.ini` se não me engano.

Comment: Uma maneira que eu sei que funciona é colocar no início do código, assim:

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Mas assim só mostra os erros da página, não faz funcionar o debug mesmo.

Comment: Não sei se é essa função é do xdebug, to tentando achar na [lista do site](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions)

Comment: Provavelmente não é uma função do `xdebug`. Talvez fosse uma função de um framework, cms, etc.

Comment: Eu usava o CakePhp, será que essa função é específica dele ?

Comment: Então é isso. O `debug()` é uma função do `CakePHP`. Segue documentação da função: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/pt/development/debugging.html

Comment: Para adicionar essa função em seu código, basta copiar esse trecho https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/basics.php#L29-L63 e incluir essa classe em seu código https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Error/Debugger.php. `É necessário fazer pequenas modificações`

Comment: Vou tentar aqui Valdeir, mas se quiser, já coloca como resposta que eu marco como correta, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como essa função não é nativa do PHP ou XDebug, não irá funcionando. Como supracitado nos comentários da pergunta, essa é uma função do CakePHP, porém, é possível adiciona-la em seu projeto.

Para isso basta seguir o passo a passo abaixo.

#### Adicionando a função em seu projeto

1. Baixe o arquivo https://pastebin.com/Eff17ysa e adicione na pasta **Cake/Error** com o nome **Debugger.php**.
2. Baixe o arquivo https://pastebin.com/jDQWA7Cs e adicione na pasta **Cake/Log** com o nome **Log.php**.
3. Baixe o arquivo https://pastebin.com/ZZHnh5Le e adicione na pasta **Cake/Utility** com o nome **Hash.php**.
4. Baixe o arquivo https://pastebin.com/mueEu8fq e adicione na pasta **Cake/Utility** com o nome **Text.php**.
5. Baixe o arquivo https://pastebin.com/VMHFMH6A e adicione na pasta **Cake** com o nome **basics.php**
6. Baixe o arquivo css https://pastebin.com/3i1sSMXz e adicione ao seu projeto (Opcional).

#### Utilizando a função `debug` em seu projeto

Para utilizar em seu projeto, basta seguir o código abaixo:

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function($classname) {
    $file = sprintf("%s.php", $classname);

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require_once $file;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("File {$file} not found", 404);
    }
});

require_once "cake/basics.php";

$json = '[
  {
    "_id": "5a4e7fe189a2b22149d1c7ec",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "a56c5543-ee29-4cf8-94df-f320eb431f55",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$2,254.23",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 24,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": "Rose Stewart",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "COMTOUR",
    "email": "rosestewart@comtour.com",
    "phone": "+1 (987) 485-2948",
    "address": "107 Schenectady Avenue, Klagetoh, Arkansas, 204",
    "about": "Ipsum sit labore in pariatur sit reprehenderit ut incididunt elit minim amet. Et occaecat est velit deserunt. Nostrud ad laboris adipisicing officia deserunt non sunt tempor qui. Labore anim in eiusmod voluptate nisi nostrud commodo amet cupidatat consectetur nostrud nulla. Culpa nisi Lorem voluptate commodo nisi. Commodo fugiat commodo tempor eiusmod excepteur. Tempor duis eiusmod pariatur reprehenderit.\r\n",
    "registered": "2014-07-02T10:14:10 +03:00",
    "latitude": 25.711449,
    "longitude": 149.030368,
    "tags": [
      "cupidatat",
      "aute",
      "incididunt",
      "Lorem",
      "sunt",
      "in",
      "ipsum"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Traci Duran"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Tanisha Burris"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Sherry Kirk"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Rose Stewart! You have 9 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "apple"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a4e7fe18afe28b610c8907d",
    "index": 1,
    "guid": "47d8f51f-74b4-4c65-a5be-78b368da58bf",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$2,457.97",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 28,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": "Phoebe Bridges",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "TELLIFLY",
    "email": "phoebebridges@tellifly.com",
    "phone": "+1 (941) 475-3973",
    "address": "374 Centre Street, Aberdeen, District Of Columbia, 1342",
    "about": "Esse consectetur anim nulla ut incididunt exercitation. Fugiat officia ad id elit sunt deserunt exercitation ullamco esse eiusmod elit commodo. Irure in exercitation occaecat irure dolor exercitation. Irure anim in labore ea cupidatat fugiat. Officia tempor elit eiusmod officia labore nostrud cillum ea. Officia reprehenderit elit Lorem Lorem nulla ullamco irure. Nulla esse officia magna cupidatat labore occaecat in labore.\r\n",
    "registered": "2015-10-07T08:16:50 +03:00",
    "latitude": 80.841288,
    "longitude": 102.12139,
    "tags": [
      "excepteur",
      "ut",
      "fugiat",
      "officia",
      "tempor",
      "ad",
      "deserunt"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Stanton Chen"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Grimes Potts"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Wilder Pope"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Phoebe Bridges! You have 1 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "apple"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a4e7fe1fdf182534ff057a7",
    "index": 2,
    "guid": "abab8774-a1bd-42f1-ba4f-5c3b19c4eb89",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,843.88",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 37,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": "Reese Jackson",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "LIQUIDOC",
    "email": "reesejackson@liquidoc.com",
    "phone": "+1 (956) 593-2808",
    "address": "852 Irvington Place, Walland, Mississippi, 7598",
    "about": "Aute quis eu consequat aliqua Lorem id magna ex anim enim esse qui id. In cupidatat voluptate ut Lorem. Laboris ipsum laborum qui in veniam est et fugiat et minim labore.\r\n",
    "registered": "2016-10-11T01:34:32 +03:00",
    "latitude": 28.71233,
    "longitude": 76.544442,
    "tags": [
      "sint",
      "id",
      "velit",
      "sunt",
      "fugiat",
      "nostrud",
      "enim"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Johnston Levy"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Tisha Bean"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Roseann Allen"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Reese Jackson! You have 8 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "strawberry"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a4e7fe10d545530d9b4290d",
    "index": 3,
    "guid": "80449941-15ce-4734-aee7-42439408d7e7",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,746.87",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 25,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Gallegos Short",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "PARAGONIA",
    "email": "gallegosshort@paragonia.com",
    "phone": "+1 (805) 521-2988",
    "address": "462 Hart Place, Lawrence, Alabama, 9109",
    "about": "Dolor occaecat ea do incididunt. Eu sit sit exercitation et quis. Minim officia proident enim enim anim nostrud est eu excepteur veniam in eu culpa. Non sit aute minim nostrud voluptate consectetur deserunt eiusmod enim incididunt id. Commodo aliquip tempor ut ad. Laborum consequat sit ullamco adipisicing consequat occaecat sunt Lorem tempor exercitation nulla deserunt minim. Nulla id elit ea pariatur aliquip elit.\r\n",
    "registered": "2017-05-11T03:32:22 +03:00",
    "latitude": -22.592765,
    "longitude": -118.326613,
    "tags": [
      "nulla",
      "minim",
      "eu",
      "sunt",
      "ut",
      "incididunt",
      "dolor"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Lea Arnold"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Marla Acosta"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Bailey Clay"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Gallegos Short! You have 8 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "strawberry"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a4e7fe169ab13c7ca60517d",
    "index": 4,
    "guid": "fb83500c-4fa0-4146-8bdf-3363b66cdd9a",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$3,613.46",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 39,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Rivers Ayers",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "QUANTASIS",
    "email": "riversayers@quantasis.com",
    "phone": "+1 (958) 479-3701",
    "address": "384 Albee Square, Noxen, Texas, 5220",
    "about": "Magna id ea in sint. Veniam esse duis ipsum commodo dolor laboris ea ut irure ea. Sunt culpa deserunt labore dolore eu ad esse amet quis excepteur deserunt laborum elit. Elit eiusmod veniam pariatur aute duis sint id et velit proident tempor commodo ut sint.\r\n",
    "registered": "2015-09-08T09:24:58 +03:00",
    "latitude": -79.499936,
    "longitude": 19.478766,
    "tags": [
      "sint",
      "mollit",
      "dolor",
      "tempor",
      "adipisicing",
      "exercitation",
      "quis"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Brandie Stevens"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Matilda Barber"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Pat Le"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Rivers Ayers! You have 3 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a4e7fe191c95b83d579b6c7",
    "index": 5,
    "guid": "2695c3ef-c4ec-4bd8-90b6-cd9384dd615a",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,350.94",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 29,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Olga England",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "GENMEX",
    "email": "olgaengland@genmex.com",
    "phone": "+1 (824) 416-2274",
    "address": "993 Garnet Street, Calpine, Virgin Islands, 8308",
    "about": "Velit ipsum labore veniam voluptate quis duis in laboris irure nisi deserunt magna. Anim irure quis aute pariatur. Magna proident do reprehenderit commodo duis sit. Est reprehenderit dolor commodo nostrud commodo minim tempor aute irure elit. Esse nisi excepteur ex excepteur sunt enim sint et duis velit proident. Do nisi nisi duis ipsum consequat nulla ipsum voluptate.\r\n",
    "registered": "2015-08-30T09:19:52 +03:00",
    "latitude": 21.195056,
    "longitude": -148.916229,
    "tags": [
      "ad",
      "id",
      "cillum",
      "nisi",
      "fugiat",
      "consectetur",
      "magna"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Herminia Parker"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Louisa Bennett"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Cross Hatfield"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Olga England! You have 8 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  }
]';

debug( json_decode($json) );
```